# Is Pokemon Go legal at all in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

The Vagrancy Act 1824 has this to say

> every Person playing or betting in any Street, Road, Highway, or other open and public Place, at or with any Table or Instrument of gaming, at
>   any Game or pretended Game' of Chance

outdated or not, I believe this is the law. So... what's the situation here?

Edit: because I was asked where did I find this, it's in http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1824/83/pdfs/ukpga_18240083_en.pdf

[image]

Comment: Why would it not be legal? Can I not play scrabble in the car? It's either about public gambling, or I don't know.

Comment: A car is not an open and public place. Scalia would say, if they meant "gambling", they would have said "gambling". Of course, Scalia is not English.

Comment: Where did you find this? http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo4/5/83/contents can you please link to the specific part/section of that statute, please?

Comment: @jimsug it's in the PDF linked from that very page.

Comment: "Gaming" was synonymous with "gambling" at the time.  A "pretended game of chance" would typically be a "game" on which adults would typically wager, but which youth would play without wagering anything of value.  This did not refer to recreation, passtimes, or amusements.

Comment: @chx right- you should _only_ refer to the _current_ text of acts, as in force - the pdf is the act as enacted, however, since then a slew of legislation has limited its effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had a good look at the [Vagrancy Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo4/5/83/contents), and I have to say that i can't find the text that you're looking for.

It's possibly been repealed, in which case it's not, in fact, the law - even if it were, it is unlikely that this provision would have applied to most games, as it appears to be Games or pretended Games of Chance that it targets.